# Controller input not being received in Wine

Tags: 14.04, wine, playonlinux, xinput

In Wine, I have a drive set up through POL that contains Steam and Rocket League. In the game, even though the controller is recognized by evtest, no input is received. I installed xinput for Wine and have all the overrides set to builtin then native, yet no input goes through.

Is there a component I'm missing?

I have checked `wine control` and the input is being received, but nothing happens in any game.